# Error : object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()

Tags: python, machine-learning, error-handling, scikit-learn, typeerror

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split  
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV

train,test,train_label,test_label=train_test_split(feature_data,target_data,test_size=0.20,random_state=3)

sc=StandardScaler()
train_std=sc.fit_transform(train)
test_Std=sc.transform(test)

pipe=SGDRegressor()
parameters = {'sgd__loss':['squared_loss','huber'],
         'sgd__n_iter':np.ceil(106/len(train_label)),
         'sgd__alpha':10.0**np.arange(1,7),             
    }
g_search=RandomizedSearchCV(pipe,param_distributions=parameters,random_state=2)
g_fit=g_search.fit(train_std,train_label)
```

---

Training Data:

```
train_std 
Out[46]:

array([[ 1.99470848,  2.39114909,  0.96705   , ...,  0.23698853,
     0.89215521, -0.74111955],
   [-0.50742363, -0.54567689, -0.29516734, ...,  0.00491999,
    -0.73959331,  0.42680023],
   [-0.46965669, -0.10483307,  0.90566027, ..., -0.34272278,
     0.69705485,  0.56151837],
   ...,
   [-0.05849323,  0.11803686,  0.45737245, ...,  0.24026818,
     0.75026404, -0.3829142 ],
   [ 0.83045625,  0.66257208, -0.01582026, ...,  0.32870492,
    -0.27844698, -0.83648146],
   [-0.0886727 ,  0.46158079,  1.36521081, ..., -0.10050365,
    -0.68638412, -0.04006983]])
```

Training Label

```
 train_label
Out[47]: 
24429     1.863
32179    18.296
42715     1.417
6486      6.562
39407    18.669
         ...
42602     6.002
6557      2.921
30305    11.835
4718      1.212
```

> Error : object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()

g_fit is causing error while fitting the training data

I am trying to use SGDRegressor by RandomizedSearchCV but this is getting an

error while fiiting the training data

Comment: Thanks for posting a block of code with no explanation of: 1) What you're trying to do, 2) What you've tried in order to solve the problem. Please read [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I am trying to implement Scikit SGDRegressor but i am getting an error while training the model  with RandomizdSeachCV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the error is caused by the value corresponding to key `'sgd__n_iter'` : `np.ceil(10**6/len(train_label))`.

So you have two options to fix this:

1. Turn it into a list:  `[np.ceil(10**6/len(train_label))]`
2. Add it right away to the constructor of `SGDRegressor` and do not put it into the `param_distributions` dictionary.

I also noticed some inconsistencies in your code so see below a minimal and slightly cleaner version of your code

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV, train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression

n_samples = 1000
n_features = 50
X, y = make_regression(n_samples=n_samples, n_features=n_features)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

pipe = Pipeline([('scaler', StandardScaler()),
                 ('sgd', SGDRegressor())])

parameters = {'sgd__loss': ['squared_loss','huber'],
              'sgd__n_iter': [np.ceil(10**6 / n_samples)],
              'sgd__alpha': 10.0**np.arange(1,7)} 

g_search = RandomizedSearchCV(pipe, param_distributions=parameters, random_state=2)

g_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: i implemented your suggestion and it is working but it is also making a warning :  
             DeprecationWarning: n_iter parameter is deprecated in 0.19 and will be 
             removed in 0.21. Use max_iter and tol instead.
             ( DeprecationWarning) can you help me how to avoid this warning

Comment: Well, its just a warning and you can ignore it. In the future, the parameter n_iter will be deleted but as of right now it is still a part of your scikit-learn version

Answer (score 2):

I guess the following line causes the mentioned error:

```
parameters = {...,
         'sgd__n_iter':np.ceil(10**6/len(train_label)), # <--- should be a list-like object, not a scalar!
         ...,             
    }
```

try the following:

```
parameters = {'sgd__loss':['squared_loss','huber'],
         'sgd__n_iter': [np.ceil(10**6/len(train_label))],
         # NOTE:        ^                               ^
         'sgd_alpha':10.0**np.arange(1,7),             
    }
```